# Object of array in new ViewController keeps empty

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsarray, nslog

I've a problem with an array.
There's an array with some objects of the class Car in my CarViewController:

...Car.h

```
@interface Car : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
```

..and Car.m

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    [coder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder;
{
    self = [[Car alloc] init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        name = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
   }
    return self;
}
```

and CarViewController

```
    Car *car1 = [Car new];
        car1.name = @"A1";
...
     cars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: car1, car2, ..., nil];
```

But when I now try to have access to this array in NewViewController there is a problem:

```
- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
CarViewController *vc = (CarViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CarVC"];

Car *car = [vc.cars objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", car.name);
}
```

But in the log is just written that **car.name = (null)**.
Thanks in advance to your effort.

**UPDATE**:

```
- (IBAction)btn:(id)sender {

 UINavigationController *nav = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1];
        CarViewController *vc = nav.topViewController;
        Car *car = [vc.cars objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"%@", car.name);
}
```

I've tried something (thanks to **rdelmar** for his effort), but the result is still the same.

Comment: Where do you create and initialise your array of cars?

Comment: Is this a typo in your question or your code? You're assigning the @"A1"-string to an object named recipe1, should this not be car1?

Comment: @schumbob is right. A1 string doesn't have a closing quote.  Did you set a breakpoint in the assignment of cars to see if it's getting called before you try to access it?

Comment: @EricGenet in the viewDidLoad-method of carViewController

Comment: How are you getting the CarViewController on screen? Your code shows that you instantiate it, but you're not doing anything in that method to put it on screen.

Comment: @rdelmar I present the cars in a tableView

Comment: That's not he question I asked -- I'm asking about the view controller itself. Show the code where you put the CarViewController on screen (or are you doing it with a segue?).

Comment: @rdelmar I use a tableViewController...just in the storyboard, not in code

Comment: If you're using a segue, that instantiates the new controller, so by calling instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier in code, you're creating a new different instance that's not the one on screen.

Comment: @rdelmar And is there a solution without creating a new instance and just using the old one?

Comment: Yes, you pass information to the destination controller of a segue in the prepareForSegue method which is called just before the segue gets performed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34548/discussion-between-bob-and-rdelmar)

Answer (score 0):

if you put this code

```
Car *car1 = [Car new];
        car1.name = @"A1";
...
     cars = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: car1, car2, ..., nil];
```

in the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller, the the result is normal because your view is not loaded yet. (the `viewDidLoad` method has not been called yet)

I'm not familiar with storyboards but I think when you call

```
CarViewController *vc = (CarViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CarVC"];
```

it will instantiate a new ViewController. So if you try to access `cars` property it will be nil if this new viewController is not presented on screen

> **Apple Documentation**
>
> You use this method to create view controller objects that
>   you want to manipulate and present programmatically in your
>   application. Before you can use this method to retrieve a view
>   controller, you must explicitly tag it with an appropriate identifier
>   string in Interface Builder.
>
> This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller
>   each time you call it.

Comment: But I load the CarViewController first, and then the NewViewController

Comment: @Bob Is the CarViewController presented on screen ?

Comment: Yes, both are presented

Comment: Can you provide more code and I'll try to figure out what's happening ? Are you using ARC ? The cars property is a strong reference ?

Comment: Yes I use ARC and `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *cars;`